# How to simulate binomial mixed effects data?

Tags: r, mixed-model, binomial-distribution

[This R code](https://gist.github.com/1370032) simulates Gaussian mixed effects data with one random effect and one fixed effect. How would I modify that code to simulate Binomial mixed effects data with one random effect and one fixed effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I solved this myself ([R code here](https://gist.github.com/1370032)). The only difference is that the line:

```
data$value[data$unit==i] = as.numeric(mm %*% means[i,]) + rnorm(k*2,0,sqrt(noise))
```

gets replaced by :

```
data$value[data$unit==i] = rbinom(k*2,1,plogis(as.numeric(mm %*% means[i,])))
```

in the `binomial(link='logit')` case, while in the `binomial(link='probit')` case, use this:

```
data$value[data$unit==i] = rbinom(k*2,1,pnorm(as.numeric(mm %*% means[i,])))
```

(The difference between the logit and probit cases is the use of `plogis` in the former and `pnorm` in the latter)